# How to get 'java -version' output through python

Tags: python, command

I tried `os.popen` and the like ways. But it does not seem to work for me. I'm wondering if there's anything different between a command `'echo xxxx'` and `'java -version'`, and how can I get `'java -version'` output with python code.

Comment: subprocess.check_output http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Comment: Read the manual of the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Why does nobody read the [documentation for os.popen](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen)? It says: "Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete. Use the subprocess module."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import subprocess
sp = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-version"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print sp.communicate()
print sp.wait()
```

is the real way to go.

An even simpler way could be

```
print subprocess.check_output(["java", "-version"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `java -version` prints to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. You can check the `stderr` of the command using `subprocess.Popen` (better) or redirect `stdout` to `stderr` manually:

```
java -version 2>&1
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the difference is that java -version goes to the stderr stream. Try popen3 http://docs.python.org/library/popen2.html

Comment: "Deprecated since version 2.6: This module is obsolete. Use the subprocess module."

Comment: So what, it's still commonly used. Lots of ppl use os.popen and I doubt it's going away in the 2.x branch (which is pretty much dead by now anyway).

Comment: If something is deprecated I wouldn't recommend it.